# ¿Cómo instalar Inspinia en symfony?

Tags: symfony2, inspinia

Tengo las librerías de INSPINIA y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poder instalarlo en symfony o como añadirlo, he añadido bootstrap sin problema alguno pero al buscar documentación sobre inspinia no he encontrado nada. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[INSPINIA](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) si es este sobre el que estas hablando, es una plantilla, la cual no se puede importar como tal, lo primero tendrás que comprar la licencia de uso si no lo has hecho ya. Una vez comprada, lo que deberías hacer, seria usar la carpeta `Static_seed_project` ya que viene a ser una plantilla vacía pero con la estructura de el nav lateral y el espacio para cargar los contenidos a la derecha ya montado.

En si lo que INSPINIA te da es un conglomerado de todo tipo de elementos que podrías utilizar en tu web, simplemente copias el código del elemento que te gusta, lo pones y te debería funcionar.

Lo único que deberías importar seria el `styles.css` de la carpeta de css y `inspinia.js` de la carpeta de js, para que coja los estilos hechos por ellos y algunas de las configuraciones iniciales de la plantilla como la minimización del menú entre otras.

Ademas gran parte de las cosas ya hechas son plugins de terceros que han customizado para dártelo ya hecho y que tu solo tengas que copiar y pegar.

Aparte del `Static_seed_project` mencionado arriba, que vendría a ser la plantilla en HTML puro, hay otras versiones como `Rails_Seed_Project` o `Angular_Seed_Project_MEANJS` que vendría a ser la misma plantilla pero amoldada para utilizarla en un entorno con `Ruby on Rail` o `AngularJS` en el stack `MEAN.io` respectivamente.

Hay ademas para los frameworks `ASP.net MVC`, `MeteorJS` entre otros, pero no tienen ninguno para `Symfony`.

Espero haberte aclaro algo, cualquier duda sobre el mismo no dudes en preguntarme ya que hago uso de el desde hace un tiempo.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido la explicación, empiezo a usarlo ahora, iré preguntando lo mas seguro, gracias por ello. Ya poseo la licencia.

Comment: Me alegra haberte aclarado, cualquier cosilla no dudes en preguntar :)

Answer (score 0):

quisiera saber si para INSPINIA existe un framework para JAVA, yo estría usando el framework de struts 1.

Gracias